# import error for -cannot import name 'train_test_split' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'

Tags: python, spyder

I wanted to import `train_test_split` to split my dataset into a test dataset and a training dataset but an import error has occurred.

I tried all of these but none of them worked:

```
conda upgrade scikit-learn
pip uninstall scipy
pip3 install scipy

pip uninstall sklearn
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install sklearn
```

Here is the code which yields the error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

And here is the error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import train_test_split
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-e25c97b1e6d9>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import train_test_split

ImportError: cannot import name 'train_test_split' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

Comment: If you're mixing conda and pip to install packages, then you most probably corrupted your installation and you need to reinstall Anaconda. That's because conda and pip packages are incompatible.

Answer (score 12):

`train_test_split` isn't in `preprocessing`, it is in `model_selection` and `cross_validation`, so you meant:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Or:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 0):

test_train_split is not present in preprocessing.
It is present in model_selection module so try.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

it will work.